# Запретить блокировку

Tags: javascript, экран

Как можно запретить блокировку экрана устройства на веб странице через js? или еще чем-то?
Нужно чтобы на странице экран был всегда включен, как при просмотре видео на полный экран

Comment: Please try NoSleep.js library

Comment: небольшой гуглёж дал понять, что браузер не блокируется сам, пока играет видео. Есть либа `nosleep.js`, кажется так называется. Но она на мобильные браузеры рассчитана. В драфте есть `wakeLock API`, но до него ещё далеко. Так что нативных вариантов я так и не нашёл.

Answer (score 1):

Библиотека [NoSleep.js](https://github.com/richtr/NoSleep.js) - браузер не блокируется сам, пока играет видео.

Comment: Хорошо бы добавить пример использовался этой библиотеки.

Comment: Лучше сначала просить ответивших в комментарии написать ответ.